# NHibernate Many-to-Many Relation: Quering the properties of the joining table

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, many-to-many

Sorry if the title is a little vague, I have the following sceneraio:
I have three tables in my domain model as following:
    [image]

there is a many to many relation between the `AddingOrder` table and `Product` table

in the Product entity i have

```
public virtual IList<AddingOrder> AddingOrders { get; set; }
```

with the following mapping:

```
<bag name="AddingOrders" generic="true" table="AddingOrderProduct">
  <key column="ProductId"/>
  <many-to-many column="OrderId" class="Application.Domain.Entities.AddingOrder,Application.Domain"/>
</bag>
```

in the AddingOrder entity i have

```
public virtual IList<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

with the following mapping file:

```
<bag name="Products" generic="true" table="AddingOrderProduct">
  <key column="OrderId"/>
  <many-to-many column="ProductId" class="Application.Domain.Entities.Product,Application.Domain"/>
</bag>
```

and this is the entity that maps to the joining table

```
public class AddingOrderProduct
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual decimal Quantity { get; set; }
    public virtual Unit Unit { get; set; }
}
```

and its mapping:

```
<id name="Id" column="Id">
  <generator class="native" >
  </generator>
</id>
<property name="Quantity" type="Decimal" column="Quantity" />
<many-to-one name="Unit" column="Id" not-null="true" class="Application.Domain.Entities.Unit,Application.Domain" />
```

So far, So good all things working fine with no problems.
the question is: **How could i query for the properties on the join table `AddingOrderProduct` and join them with the two other sides of the relation??** (the two other tables), **do i need an extra mapping between this table and the two other tables**, for example the following is a sql query that returns the list of products with there quantity and unit that belong to the order #1 the name of the product form the product table and the quantity and unit id from the joining table AddingOrderProduct and the order id from the AddingOrder table:

```
select  p.Name ,aop.Quantity ,u.Name
from   Product p 
     inner join AddingOrderProduct aop on p.Id = aop.ProductId 
     inner join AddingOrder ao on ao.Id = aop.OrderId
     inner join Unit u on u.Id = aop.UnitId
where ao.Id = 1
```

how can i write this query with NHibernate with the mentioned mappings
i omitted a lot of code just for simplicity and there is no direct mappings one-to-many between the AddingOrderProduct and the two other tables. and for the unit entity forget about it it is not an issue.

Thanks in advance;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use many-to-many. Use a one-to-many from `Product` and `AddingOrder` to `AddingOrderProduct` and collections of `AddingOrderProduct` in the code.

Comment: so i have to delete the two many to many relations between the two tables and add two one-to-many reltions between the AddingOrderProduct and the two other tables so that i can query for the properties in the join table there is no way than this???. but i didn't want to do this i want to use the many to many relation and it is working now i have order.Products and product.Orders and i can query for them, it is not the problem, the problem is how i can query for the properties on the joining table the AddingOrderProduct like the sql query mentioned in the question, thanks

Comment: @MGA Yes, I don't know any other way.